# Dropdownlist validation in Asp.net Using Required field validator

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have Dropdownlist whose value field and text field are bind at runtime.
it has `--select--` as first item with a value of `0`
and the rest of the values are bind at runtime.

I have given validaton group for both the control and the validator as `"g1"`
and `Intialvalue=0`

But still the page is posting  back even if I select `--select--` option.

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="dropdown" ValidationGroup="g1" 
    ID="ddlReportType" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlReportType_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="ddlReportType" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
ValidationGroup="g1" CssClass="errormesg" ErrorMessage="Please select a type"
InitialValue="0" runat="server"  Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

And code Behind to Bind the Dropdown

```
ddlReportType.Items.Clear();
ddlReportType.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
ddlReportType.DataTextField = "ReportType";
ddlReportType.DataValueField = "ReportTypeID";
ddlReportType.DataBind();
ddlReportType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
//ddlReportType.Items[0].Value = "0";
ddlReportType.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ID="Req_ID" Display="Dynamic" 
    ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ControlID"
    Text="*" ErrorMessage="ErrorMessage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Please verify you have put above code in if(!IsPostback){} method

Comment: yes it is inside if(!IsPostback){} and I calling that code behid mehtod on some radio button change event

Comment: Hey after Adding Causesvalidation=True for drop down it is firing at client side without  posting back to server.or U can see this link          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392079/validation-message-still-show-up-when-an-autopostback-dropdownlist-fires

Comment: Could you explain what the `InitialValue="-1"` does?

Comment: Initial Value is the value to compare against, so in this example it should be "0".

Answer (score 8):

Here use asp:CompareValidator, and compare the value to "select" option.

Use `Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="0"` to prevent the user from submitting the "select".

```
<asp:CompareValidator ControlToValidate="ddlReportType" ID="CompareValidator1"
    ValidationGroup="g1" CssClass="errormesg" ErrorMessage="Please select a type"
    runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
    Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="0" Type="Integer" />
```

When you do above, if you select the "select " option from dropdown it will show the `ErrorMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a few days until I chanced on the issue when I had to build a new Dropdown.  I had several DropDownList controls and attempted to get validation working with no luck. One was databound and the other was filled from the aspx page. I needed to drop the databound one and add a second manual list. In my case Validators failed if you built a dropdown like this and looked at any value (0 or -1) for either a required or compare validator:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Reason" CssClass="inputDropDown" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>                                                                                                
<asp:ListItem>Expired</asp:ListItem>                                                                                                
<asp:ListItem>Lost/Stolen</asp:ListItem>                                                                                                
<asp:ListItem>Location Change</asp:ListItem>                                                                                            
</asp:DropDownList>
```

However adding the InitialValue like this worked instantly for a compare Validator.

```
<asp:ListItem Text="-- Select --" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `InitialValue="0"` in Required field validator tag

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ID="Req_ID"
      Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="ControlID"
      InitialValue="0" ErrorMessage="ErrorMessage">
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Why do you have `InitialValue="-1"` and `InitialValue="0"`?

Comment: @nueverest, In most cases, when I develop data to be filled into a Drop Down, the default item "Select...." is usually assigned a non-positive and non-zero value, hence -1.  For zero-based value systems, this allows the developer to check for `<0` and for one-based value systems, same policy `<0`.