# RequiredFieldValidator Not Working in ComboBox

Tags: asp.net, combobox, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, asp.net-validators

I think one common problem in using ComboBox is that the RequiredFieldValidator is not working properly on it.

I also tried:
1. CustomValidator
2. CompareValidator

But none of it is working. Please help.

CompareValidator

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="CompareFieldValidator1" 
ErrorMessage="This field cannot be empty" ControlToValidate="CB_Operation" 
ValueToCompare="-1" Operator="NotEqual"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

RequiredFieldValidator

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"ControlToValidate="CB_Indication"
runat="server" ErrorMessage="This field cannot be empty" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Here is the mark-up of one of my ComboBoxes

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="CB_Operation" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
 Font-Size="Small" Width="170px" Font-Bold="True" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="CB_Operation_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" InitialValue="0">

  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Add</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Modify</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:ComboBox>
```

Comment: can we see your combobox too

Comment: Have a look at this: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310609/dropdownlist-validation-in-asp-net-using-required-field-validator)

Comment: Hi! It's now working. I just added "Initial Value = -1", removed the Validation Group, set display to dynamic and voila! MANY THANKS! :D